# Closing a modal dialog using a custom form

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am using some JavaScript (Client OM) code to open a dialog.  Here's a snippet:

```
    function OpenModalForm() {

    //snip

    var opt = {
        url: url,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: title || "",
        dialogReturnValueCallback: OnDialogClose
    };

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(opt);
}

    function OnDialogClose(dialogResult, returnValue) {
    alert("dialog result: " + dialogResult );

    if ( dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK ) {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
    }
    if ( dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel ) {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Cancel);
    }
}
```

This dialog opens a custom form. The problem is the callback is not fired when pressing save or cancel.  The callback is fired if I click the upper-right hand X of the modal.  How do I get the call back to fire when clicking the buttons on the custom form?

***Note***
Everything works as expected on OOTB forms.  I have hard coded the custom form buttons to run the commonModalDialogClose and that works.  I'm trying to ***not*** do that.  I'd like to take advantage of the callback, if at all possible.

***Update***
This is the HTML rendered for the buttons:

```
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=4 width="100%" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<TBODY>
    <TR>
        <TD class=ms-vb noWrap><INPUT onclick="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$***SNIP***','__commit')" name=btnSave value=Save type=button jQuery16406037463754413849="2"></TD>
        <TD class=ms-vb width="99%" noWrap><INPUT onclick="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$***SNIP***','__cancel')" name=btnCancel value=Cancel type=button jQuery16406037463754413849="1"></TD>
    </TR>
</TBODY>
```

Comment: For clarity, it would be great if you could post the code of your form. At least the "buttons" part of the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried using the same controls that OOTB modal dialog forms use? You'll probably need to, as those will trip javascript functions needed for the callback.

Comment: I have not tried to use those controls. I'll check to see if they are available within SharePoint Designer.  Do you know if they are?

Comment: You'll probably have to have a look into the LAYOUTS folder and see what application pages are loaded. Or perhaps even the ControlTemplates folder, as it'll probably be loaded via usercontrol.

Comment: I'll give it a go...  Thanks for the insight as always.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking at the same challenge a couple of months back.
Project ended up being cancelled but would the section of this post:
http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx
help in any way?

```
this.Page.Response.Clear(); 
this.Page.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, 1);</script>"); 
this.Page.Response.End();
```

There is another post with an example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/09/14/modal-dialog-box-in-sharepoint-sandbox.aspx

Comment: Thanks Greg for the great link.  I tried the code: Function.createDelegate, but I didn't have any success with it.  Any tips on how to use the callback within SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog?

Answer (score 2):

After looking into it, there are two ways of creating a custom form.  One via the ribbon and one from the Data Source Details pane.  The first way produces controls with code similar to:

```
<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
    <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>
</td>
<td class="ms-separator"> </td>
<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
    <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2"/>
</td>
```

The second way of creating a custom form produces code similar to:

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb">
    <input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}" />
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb" width="99%">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" />
</td>
```

Using the latter, you lose control of firing the callback.  So the fix is to change the code to use the SharePoint control and not rely on the ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent.  This will fire the callback as intended.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: onclick=”window.frameElement.commitPopup(); return false;”

Comment: I'd like to use the callback within the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog if possible.  I'm thinking it's not possible, but I don't know why it's that way.